# dynamic SQL - Allocate count of midnights to correct month

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

This is a fairly common issue that I've seen a lot of people duck tape together solutions for, but it's never quite right. Hoping this forum can get it ironed out. I have a table:

```
create table temp
(   PatientID varchar(12),
    AdmitDate datetime,
    DischargeDate datetime
)

insert into temp values ('Patient1','1/30/2020 13:23:44', '2/2/2020 15:12:52')
```

What I'd like to count is the number of midnights the patient was admitted in the correct month. So in the example above the patient would be admitted at midnight on 1/31, 2/1, and 2/2 dates. So my output in sql should look something like:

```
    01-2020         02-2020
    -------         --------
       1                2
```

I know it has to be dynamic SQL, because the columns need to be created with respect to the date range queried. Although, I'm pretty stumped as to next steps.

Comment: .Suppose Patient2 Admin date='3/30/2020 13:23:44' and dischange date is '5/30/2020 13:23:44'.Then what will output look like.Do you want to see all patient report between specific period ?Plz provide same data of 3 patient and output.In my example you can see there is gap in month of Admit and discharge date.Answer depend upon all these thing.Reply fast.

Comment: `I'm pretty stumped as to next steps` L If requirement is to show for single patient and difference in month between AdmitDate and discharge date are always 1 then solution is simple.If result is require for many Patient and across date range then solution is altogether different..So next step really depend upon your actual requirement.

Comment: Thanks @KumarHarsh for your assisntance. The answer to this question was actually posted elsewhere. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599562/sql-server-query-for-total-number-of-days-for-a-month-between-date-ranges . I've posted my version of the answer below though as I suspect others can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #temp 
(   PatientID varchar(12),
    AdmitDate datetime,
    DischargeDate datetime
)

insert into #temp values ('Patient1','1/30/2020 13:23:44', '2/2/2020 15:12:52')

    --Virtually creates a dates table
;with dates(thedate) as (
  select dateadd(yy,years.number,0)+days.number
    from master..spt_values years
    join master..spt_values days
      on days.type='P' and days.number < datepart(dy,dateadd(yy,years.number+1,0)-1)
   where years.type='P' and years.number between 100 and 150
      -- note: 100-150 creates dates in the year range 2000-2050
      --       adjust as required
)

select dateadd(m,datediff(m, 0, d.thedate),0) [Month], count(1) PatientDays
    from dates d
    join #temp t on d.thedate between t.[AdmitDate] and t.[DischargeDate]
group by datediff(m, 0, d.thedate)
order by [Month];
```