# How to determine the number of days in a month for a given Date Range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, recursive-query

I need to calculate using SQL Query, how many days within a given range fall into each calendar month.

I have given 2 dates, which define a date range; for example 2020-01-01 to 2020-08-03. I need to find how many days in that range fall in to each month i.e. how many fall into July, and how many into August.

In the example given, the expected result is 31 days in July and 3 days in August.

Comment: Create and implement a Calendar Table.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are different products...

Comment: The dates are dynamic, it can be like 2020-07-20 to 2020-09-10

Comment: There's plenty of ways to generate each individual day inside a date range in SQL, just google something along the lines of "sql return day in date range".  Depending upon your use-case you may opt for a TVF or write it all within this query.  Then group by year/month and count the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a recusive query. Using date artithmetics, we can build the query so it performs one iteration per month rather than one per day, so this should be a rather efficient approach:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        datefromparts(year(@dt_start), month(@dt_start), 1) month_start,
        1 - day(@dt_start) + day(
            case when @dt_end > eomonth(@dt_start)
                then eomonth(@dt_start) 
                else @dt_end
            end
        ) as no_days
    union all
    select 
        dateadd(month, 1, month_start),
        case when @dt_end > dateadd(month, 2, month_start) 
            then day(eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, month_start)))
            else day(@dt_end)
        end
    from cte
    where dateadd(month, 1, month_start) <= @dt_end
)
select * from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13b11837174d02fbe6d95d2f1aa85474)**.

If we set the boundaries as follows:

```
declare @dt_start date = '2020-07-10';
declare @dt_end   date = '2020-09-10';
```

Then the query returns:

```
month_start | no_days
:---------- | ------:
2020-07-01  |      22
2020-08-01  |      31
2020-09-01  |      10
```

Comment: need "OPTION (maxrecursion 0)", otherwise more than 100 months cannot be calculated

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this

```
;with dates(thedate) as (
  select dateadd(yy,years.number,0)+days.number
    from master..spt_values years
    join master..spt_values days
      on days.type='p' and days.number < datepart(dy,dateadd(yy,years.number+1,0)-1)
   where years.type='p' and years.number between 100 and 150
      -- note: 100-150 creates dates in the year range 2000-2050
      --       adjust as required
)
  select dateadd(m,datediff(m, 0, d.thedate),0) themonth, count(1)
    from dates d
   where d.thedate between '2020-01-01' and '2020-08-03'
group by datediff(m, 0, d.thedate)
order by themonth;
```

Please refer the link below where RichardTheKiwi user given a clear example for your scenario.

[SQL Server query for total number of days for a month between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599562/sql-server-query-for-total-number-of-days-for-a-month-between-date-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

You can do all the work at the month level rather than the day level -- which should be a bit faster.  Here is a method using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select @startdate as startdate, @enddate as enddate,
             datefromparts(year(@startdate), month(@startdate), 1) as month
      union all
      select startdate, enddate, dateadd(month, 1, month)
      from cte
      where dateadd(month, 1, month) < @enddate
     )
select month,
       (case when month <= startdate and dateadd(month, 1, month) >= enddate
             then day(enddate) - day(startdate) + 1
             when month <= startdate
             then day(eomonth(month)) - day(startdate) + 1
             when dateadd(month, 1, month) < enddate
             then day(eomonth(month))
             when dateadd(month, 1, month) >= enddate
             then day(enddate)
        end)
from cte;
```

And the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c3f4a5935fc74f3ad19e5aa273630a7).

The logic is simpler at the day level:

```
with cte as (
      select @startdate as dte, @enddate as enddate
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), enddate
      from cte
      where dte < enddate
     )
select datefromparts(year(dte), month(dte), 1) as yyyymm, count(*)
from cte
group by datefromparts(year(dte), month(dte), 1) 
order by yyyymm
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with recursive CTE.

```
declare @startDate date = '2020-07-01'
declare @endDate   date = '2020-08-03'


; WITH cte (n, year, month, daycnt) 
AS (
    SELECT 
        0
        , DATEPART(year,         @startDate)
        , DATENAME(MONTH,        @startDate)
        , DATEPART(day, EOMONTH( @startDate ) ) - DATEPART(day, @startDate ) + 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT    
        n + 1
        , DATEPART(year,         DATEADD(month, n + 1, @startDate) )
        , DATENAME(MONTH,        DATEADD(month, n + 1, @startDate) ) 
        , IIF(
            n = ( DATEPART(month, @endDate) - DATEPART(month, @startDate) ) + ( DATEPART(year, @endDate) - DATEPART(year, @startDate) ) * 12 - 1
            , DATEPART(day, @endDate ) 
            , DATEPART(day, EOMONTH( DATEADD(month, n + 1, @startDate) ) )
        )
    FROM    
        cte
    WHERE 
        n <= ( DATEPART(month, @endDate) - DATEPART(month, @startDate) ) + ( DATEPART(year, @endDate) - DATEPART(year, @startDate) ) * 12 - 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY n
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

This could be further simplified with a number function but that would also be essentially be a recursive CTE, though it would definitely look cleaner. But it requires defining a function on top of this SELECT statement.